# Spring Boot, TestContainers and jOOq - debugging the values during test runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, jooq, testcontainers

I was having confusing setup where I was getting an object back with SELECT where the ID was null. I wanted to debug the setup so I tried to connect to the postgres instance launched by TestContainers.

I didn't find proper documentation but going into the container with `docker exec -it ID bash` + `printenv` showed that the credentials would be `test` + `test`. Not sure if it's intended that you shouldn't go dig into the spawned container with test containers, but I wanted to troubleshoot the issue.

I am running my application where I'm getting following logs from the application

```
13:15:37.898 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Executing query          : insert into "public"."order" ("id", ...) values (?, ...)
13:15:37.899 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - -> with bind values      : insert into "public"."order" ("id", ...) values (1, ...)
13:15:37.909 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Affected row(s)          : 1
13:15:37.939 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Executing query          : insert into "public"."customer" ("id", "order_id", ..) values (?, ?, ...) returning "public"."customer"."id"
13:15:37.939 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - -> with bind values      : insert into "public"."customer" ("id", "order_id", ..) values (1, 1, ...) returning "public"."customer"."id"
13:15:37.948 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Fetched result           : +----+
13:15:37.948 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |  id|
13:15:37.948 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +----+
13:15:37.948 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : |   1|
13:15:37.948 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener -                          : +----+
13:15:37.948 [main] DEBUG org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener - Fetched row(s)           : 1
```

Code in question would be like this with jOOq.

```
public Mono<Long> insertCustomerM(Customer customer) {
    return Mono.from(
            dsl.insertInto(CUSTOMER).set(dsl.newRecord(CUSTOMER, customer)).returningResult(CUSTOMER.ID)
    ).mapNotNull(Record1::value1);
}
...
var customerM = repository.insertCustomerM(customer);
var value = customerM.block();
System.out.println("ID here " + value); // will be 1 in runtime, breakpoint here so that the application + DB doesn't terminate
```

However, when I check into the database, I'm getting the following result set back.

```
test=# select * from public.customer;
id | order_id | ...     
---+----------+-----+--
(0 rows)
```

How is it possible that with the test setup INSERT goes fine with the database driver, but after that when I manually dig into the database

Comment: Because the transaction hasn't committed yet. Not committed is not in the database for other transactions.

Comment: Are you using jOOQ's transaction API here?  There's currently a bug, which may prevent commits from happening: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13802